# Spring social - Implicit sign up is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, single-sign-on, spring-social

I am the  the Spring Social along with Spring MVC to connect to the `twitter`. 
I want to achieve an implicit sign up, if the user is new so I am following this [spring social docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#implicit-sign-up). I am getting the following error, when the application is deployed

```
 ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpringSocialConfigurer depends on org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceLocator. No single bean of that type found in application context.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpringSocialConfigurer depends on org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceLocator. No single bean of that type found in application context.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 23 more
```

This is how my  socialConfig.java is

```
package org.springframework.social.showcase.config;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.social.UserIdSource;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.ConnectionFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.EnableSocial;
import org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.social.connect.Connection;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactoryLocator;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionSignUp;
import org.springframework.social.connect.UsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController;
import org.springframework.social.connect.web.ReconnectFilter;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.web.DisconnectController;
import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedIn;
import org.springframework.social.linkedin.connect.LinkedInConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.social.showcase.account.AccountConnectionSignUp;
import org.springframework.social.showcase.account.AccountRepository;
import org.springframework.social.showcase.facebook.PostToWallAfterConnectInterceptor;
import org.springframework.social.showcase.signin.SimpleSignInAdapter;
import org.springframework.social.showcase.twitter.TweetAfterConnectInterceptor;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter;
import org.springframework.social.twitter.connect.TwitterConnectionFactory;


@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("twitter.appKey"), env.getProperty("twitter.appSecret")));
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("facebook.appKey"), env.getProperty("facebook.appSecret")));
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new LinkedInConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("linkedin.appKey"), env.getProperty("linkedin.appSecret")));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {         
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
                if (authentication == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
                }
                return authentication.getName();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator, Encryptors.noOpText());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectController connectController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        ConnectController connectController = new ConnectController(connectionFactoryLocator, connectionRepository);
        connectController.addInterceptor(new PostToWallAfterConnectInterceptor());
        connectController.addInterceptor(new TweetAfterConnectInterceptor());
        return connectController;
    }

    @Bean
    public DisconnectController disconnectController(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, Environment environment) {
        return new DisconnectController(usersConnectionRepository, environment.getProperty("facebook.appSecret"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ReconnectFilter apiExceptionHandler(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, UserIdSource userIdSource) {
        return new ReconnectFilter(usersConnectionRepository, userIdSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Facebook facebook(ConnectionRepository repository) {
        Connection<Facebook> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Twitter twitter(ConnectionRepository repository) {
        Connection<Twitter> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public LinkedIn linkedin(ConnectionRepository repository) {
        Connection<LinkedIn> connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(LinkedIn.class);
        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }

//  @Bean
//  public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController() {
//      return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator(), 
//          usersConnectionRepository(accountRepository), new SimpleSignInAdapter());
//  }
//  @Bean
//  @Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
//  public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
//      ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
//      
//      
//              
//      registry.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(
//          environment.getProperty("twitter.consumerKey"),
//          environment.getProperty("twitter.consumerSecret")));
//              
//      return registry;
//  }
    @Bean
    @Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();

        registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
        environment.getProperty("facebook.clientId"),
        environment.getProperty("facebook.clientSecret")));

        registry.addConnectionFactory(new TwitterConnectionFactory(
        environment.getProperty("twitter.consumerKey"),
        environment.getProperty("twitter.consumerSecret")));

        return registry;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value="singleton", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(
        dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator(), Encryptors.noOpText());
        repository.setConnectionSignUp((ConnectionSignUp) new AccountConnectionSignUp(accountRepository));
        return repository;
    }

}
```